# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ where the $f_n$'s are right continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

For any $n \geq 1$, let $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non negative, increasing right continuous function.

I wonder if one can say anything about $F = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$. In particular I'd like to know if $F$ is necessarily right continuous.

Do we need any assumptions on the convergence of $F$ here?

Any comments and remarks would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 1/2$, and $f_n(x) = x-1/2$ if $x > 1/2$. Then the $f_n$ are all continuous. However, $F(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 1/2$, and $F(x) = +\infty$ if $x > 1/2$.

Comment: $F$ is nondecreasing, so on the interval it is finite (possibly empty) it is continuous, except on a countable set. Finally, think of the following example: $(q_n)$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, and $f_n (x) = 2^{-n} {\bf 1}_{[q_n,1]}(x)$ (right-continuous, with only one discontinuity).  Observe that the series converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(n + 1)^{2 - x}}$. It is clearly  positive, continuous and increasing in $[0, 1]$ for all integer $n \geq 1$.

Yet for $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \zeta(2-x) - 1$ we see a discontinuity at $x = 1$. In particular, it is not right continuous.